# Set SQL SUM() query to a PHP variable, and echo result

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to pull in the sum of all values in a database column, assign it to a PHP variable and display the value.

```
$total_drop_query = mysqli_query("SELECT SUM(total_drops) FROM pi_data");

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($total_drop_query);

$total_drops = $row['total_drops'];

echo $total_drops;
```

This code isn't displaying any results, and it's driving me crazy!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're not checking for any errors and that is driving us crazy! ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Have you *connected* to the database?

Comment: Have you debugged by looking at the print_r() of the other variables? That might help you narrow it down a little bit.

Comment: `var_dump($row)` would show you EXACTLY what you need to do.

Comment: I `var_dump($row)` and just get a NULL value.  I am connected to the database, and the connection is successful, and using an `or die(mysqli_error())` on the query, I think the query is successful.

Answer (score 2):

You are not  printing  SUM but 'total_drops' value ,
 that in sql you have not select.
It's good thing to use an alias when you use SUM or Count in sql:

```
SELECT SUM(total_drops) AS something FROM pi_data"
```

so:

```
$total_drops = $row['something'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I've set up a table with your structure - 
the query works well so I think that you have the error in 
accessing the data.

I suggest you using aliases

```
SELECT SUM(total_drops) AS a FROM pi_data
```

access is possible via

```
$total_drops = $row['a'];
```